# Cant View Module From Open Cart Admin

Tags: module, opencart

Hi Everyone hope all well. I am having a weird issue in Opencart. I have installed three different modules onto my opencart ( seo pro, total import pro and Image manager plus). I have installed them correctly and have added user permissions. The weird thing is that they dont show up in the Admin navigation.

[image]

Normally Seo Pro Comes under the catalog menu. The Total Import Pro comes under the systems menu and the Image Manager Plus comes under the Extensions menu. For some weird reason none of them appear. This is the same if i add any extensions. I have done this many times on other sites and never had a problem but for the life of me can not work out why they wont appear.

They are installed because when i call upon them from the url i can view them and use them but they just dont display on the navigation bar

http://www.top4pets.co.uk/admin/index.php?route=tool/total_import&token=#####################

Has anyone ever had this problem or know what it could be?

Comment: Why don't you ask developers of these extensions to help you?

Comment: Did you play with the `header.tpl` of administration? Did you check the vQmod error logs?

Answer (score 0):

**Total Import Pro** adds the menu option with the help of vQmod. You can download and install vqmod by the instructions written here: [Installing vQmod on OpenCart](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart)

If the extensions have a folder named vqmod or files with .xml extension, then are likely to require vqmod to run properly.